# Как правильно объявлять нефиксированный список типизированный List

Tags: dart

Как правильно объявлять нефиксированный список типизированный List, как в 1 варианте или как во 2 варианте или оба варианта правильные? Компилятор ошибок не выдает.

```
void main() {
 //1 вариант
 List ara1 = <int>[];
 //2 вариант
 List<int> ara2 = [];
 
 print(ara1.runtimeType); //List<int>
 print(ara2.runtimeType); //List<int>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд Второй вариант правильный, т.к. явно указывает тип в таком варианте:

```
List ara1;
List<int> ara2; // тип указывается явно
```

См. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-core/List-class.html

Comment: Уважаемый santavital! Огромное Вам спасибо! Я начинаю предполагать, что 1 вариант это для var ara = <int>[] ,а 2 вариант это List<int> ara = [];

Answer (score 1):

Вообще если говорить о правильности, то самый правильный вариант будет таким:

```
List<int> ara = <int>[];
```

`List<int>` мы указываем для анализатора (и так более удобно понимать что за тип), а `<int>[]` мы указываем для того чтобы точно быть уверенными что в runtime не будет проблем с типами (например при работе с не явным типом).